# Bulk import via API (SOAP/REST)

Tags: spring-batch, etl, bulk-load

I have an application wherein I need to import data from the client's system into my application. This data needs to be converted in a format required by my application. Also, the data needs to be updated periodically.

So I am talking about two things here:

- Initial bulk upload
- Updating this data when data changes in the client's system.

I did my research around this, people have suggested that initial data can be uploaded through a file.

Are there any other options for this?

Let's say I need to import products and users (around 1k) into my system.

So my questions are :

1. Should I do bulk upload through some file? or Can a SOAP/REST API  be used to import the huge number of records?
2. Can I use Spring-batch in this scenario as ETL?

The solution I see right now is providing API on my server which will be called by clients system and then handing over this data to a Job(using spring-batch) for further processing.

I am using Spring framework and MySQL DB.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

The initial import can be done with a Spring Batch job. Spring Batch shines in this kind of ETL use cases with its chunk-oriented processing model, especially when you have a huge data set.

> The solution I see right now is providing API on my server which will be called by clients system

For deltas, I'm not sure YOU need to expose an API. I think it is the other system that should provide such an API to provide data changes in a given range of date/time. Then, your system can call this API regularly to grab the deltas and update itself. This can be also done with a scheduled batch job (or not, if the deltas are small enough to be processed in a web request).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either use SOAP/REST API or Read from a file. I have done both ways. 1k is very small number. I have done for 10k using Rest API. Most of the organizations have network limitations on the response size of an API. Make sure your Rest/SOAP response size is within your organization's limit. If it exceeds, prefer loading through a file using Spring batch.

In you ItemReader, create a method called init() annotated with @PostConstruct. And call your Rest/SOAP endpoint or read from file to fetch data. Your reader should return one record/line at a time where as your ItemProcessor should parse the line/record sent by reader and do further processing.

I hope this helps.